# Packaging DLL file with my application

Tags: visual-c++, dll, c++-cli, release

When I moved my C++/CLI application to another Win 7 machine, it said that `MSVCR100.dll` is missing although that was a release version of the application. What is the file `MSVCR100.dll` ? Is it possible to combine it with my application,if how? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVCR100.dll is part of the VC++ 2010 runtime; it's a dedicated downloadable from Microsoft and required for most programs compiled with VC++ 2010.

<strike>Due to the newish side-by-side (SxS) deployment of DLLs, it's not so simple to extract the handful of files and deploy them manually.</strike>

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328

Apparently, SxS is so 2008.  Visual C++ 2010 just uses all different filenames for everything.

Comment: Thanks Joe, but how can make my application install `VC++ 2010 Redistributable` then install itself?

Comment: Do you package your program in an installer now?

Comment: Then, I'd probably instruct my users to run that install first (for the VC2010 redistributable).  Your program won't be able to run until it's installed.

Comment: There is no programmable way to do that?

Comment: SxS deployment is oldish, VS2010 no longer uses it.

Comment: @Adban : Sure there is, but the details are specific to each installer platform and you haven't indicated which you intend to use. In any case, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx) is a good place to start reading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the .NET Framework and the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable
are both installed on the new machine, either that, or package the necessary dlls with your deployment.

Comment: It is not the .NET runtime.  MSVCR100.dll is from the VC++ 2010 Redistributable - they are different things.

Comment: @Joe : You should post that as an answer. :-]

Comment: Your original answer was correct.  Both the .NET Framework and Visual C++ runtime are needed to run a C++/CLI application.

Comment: @Ben: Thats what I thought, but the downvotes for some reason made me change my mind.. answer updated